# How can I make my javascript run faster and asynchronously

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an extension that adds some HTML to a page as it's loaded. Long story short, it gets a list of links in a table, loads those links, and grabs a specific string and adds it to the original page I loaded.

Here is the code: due to the way the webpage was coded, i couldn't get the unique ids because they didn't exist so ignore that part.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    url = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href');
    insert = rows[i].insertCell(-1);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            //var Data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var htmlString = xhr.responseText
              , parser = new DOMParser()
              , doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString,"text/html")
              , test = doc.getElementById('page-wrapper').children[1]
              , ip_address = doc.getElementsByClassName('col-md-5')[0].children[5].children[0].children[0].children[10].innerHTML;
            insert.innerHTML = ip_address;
          }

    };
      xhr.open("GET",url,false);
      xhr.send();
    }
```

when i call the function, it works fine, however it takes a really long time to load and it all loads at the end rather than updating as each iteration of the for loop completes. I'd like to decrease the time it takes to load but a significant amount, and possibly have ear row update instantly vs at the end. I've tried searching asycn javascript but the bit of code I tried didn't help me much. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you somehow forced to use oldschool Javascript?

Comment: Because if not:     ```url = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]``` looks better ```url = rows[i].querySelector('td:nth-of-type(1) a:nth-of-type(1)').getAttribute('href')```

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov Why not just `rows[i].querySelector('td a')`?

Comment: @JordanRunning Ehhh.... You rite. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using modern Javascript:

```js
rows.forEach(row => {
  fetch(row.querySelector('td:first-of-type a:first-of-type').getAttribute('href'))
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    // do manipulations with DOM
  })
  .catch(console.log)
})
```

Comment: Never use `forEach`. With promises, using `map` and `Promise.all` is more appropriate anyway.

Comment: Why not forEach? Promise.all not good 'cause it will wait until finish all requests ( which may never happen )

Comment: I think `for … of` should be preferred (almost) everywhere, it is cleaner and can handle control flow statements appropriately. And yes, you will *want* to wait with some things until all requests are finished (which is the expected outcome of the code).